# Data structure for storing ranges of data with timeline

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I need to store the activity log data for users in my application. It includes the the time when the user started doing an activity. For e.g., at 1 PM, the started 'Activity A'. At 2 PM, the user started 'Activity B'. At 3 PM, the user started 'Avtivity A'. From these logs, I should later be able to query information like

1. How long was the user doing Activity A between 12 AM to 8 PM?
2. How many times did the user switch activities etc.

Can anyone suggest what would be a good in-memory data structure to store such information?

Edit: There could be thousands of logs. A user can't do multiple activities at the same time.

Comment: how many activity will you have? and can user do multiple activity at the same time?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic - There could be thousands of records. A user can't do multiple activities at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's try to have a data structure for you to make the query assuming you have a single activity.

So let's have a list to store the timestamps (I am considering an integer example).

```
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

In this, you can store the timestamps. Let's say you have stored

```
integers.add(1);
integers.add(10);
integers.add(12);
integers.add(176);
integers.add(1678);
```

Now you need to way to access the only specific set of values in it. Consider the NavigableSet class from JDK.

```
NavigableSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(integers);
```

You can query specific set using

```
set.subSet(0, 175); // this will give 1,10,12 from the above values
```

Now Have a map to store multiple Activities.

```
Map<String, List> activityTimeStampmap= new HashMap<>();
```

You can add Activity if it does not exist, You have to update the list if Activity Already exists.

Hope this helps you.